# Grouping a row into multiple groups with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a set of sentences, and I want to group them such all the rows in a group should share one particular word. However a sentence can belong to many groups because it has many words in it.

So in the example below, there should be a groups like this:

- A 'temperature' group that includes all the rows (0, 1, 2, 3 and 4)
- A 'freezes' group which includes rows 2 and 4
- A 'the' group that includes rows 0, 1, 2, and 3
- A 'metal' group that only contains row 0.
- Groups for every other word in the dataset

```
import pandas as pd

# An example data set
df = pd.DataFrame({"sentences": [
    "two long pieces of metal fixed together, each of which bends a different amount when they are both heated to the same temperature",
    "the temperature at which a liquid boils",
    "a system for measuring temperature that is part of the metric system, in which water freezes at 0 degrees and boils at 100 degrees",
    "a unit for measuring temperature. Measurements are often expressed as a number followed by the symbol °",
    "a system for measuring temperature in which water freezes at 32º and boils at 212º"
]})

# Create a new series which is a list of words in each "sentences" column
df['words'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda sentence: sentence.split(" "))

# Try to group by this new column 
df.groupby('words').count()

# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

<strike>However my code throws an error as shown.</strike> (see below)
Since my task is a bit complicated I know it probably involves more than just calling groupby(). Can someone help me to make word groups with pandas?

*edit* After solving the error by returning `tuple(sentence.split())` (thanks ethan-furman), I try printing the result, but it doesn't seem to have done anything. I think it probably just put each row in a group:

```
print(df.groupby('words').count())

# sentences    5
# dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution uses pandas' MultiIndex feature. I'm sure it can be improved with some more efficient use of numpy, but I believe this will perform significantly better than the other python-only answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# An example data set
df = pd.DataFrame({"sentences": [
    "two long pieces of metal fixed together, each of which bends a different amount when they are both heated to the same temperature",
    "the temperature at which a liquid boils",
    "a system for measuring temperature that is part of the metric system, in which water freezes at 0 degrees and boils at 100 degrees",
    "a unit for measuring temperature. Measurements are often expressed as a number followed by the symbol °",
    "a system for measuring temperature in which water freezes at 32º and boils at 212º"
]})

# Create a new series which is a list of words in each "sentences" column
df['words'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda sentence: sentence.split(" "))

# This is all the words in the dataset. Each word will be its own index (level of the MultiIndex)
names = np.unique(df['words'].sum())

# Create an array of tuples, one tuple for each row of data
# Each tuple contains True if the row has that word in it, and False if it does not
values = df['words'].map(
    lambda words: np.vectorize(
        lambda word:
            True if word in words else False)(names)
)

# Make a multindex
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(values, names=names)

# Add the MultiIndex without creating a new data frame
df.set_index(index, inplace=True)

# Find all the rows that have the word 'temperature'
xs = df.xs(True, level='temperature')

print(xs.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: Is this solution still valid? Did You find sth better?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set collection so that each word is unique.  First, we need to get a list of all words in all of the sentences.  To do this, we initialize words to an empty set, then use a list comprehension to add each lower case word in each sentence (after splitting the sentence).

Next, we use a dictionary comprehension to build a dictionary keyed off of each word in the word set.  The value is the dataframe containing each sentence that contains that word.  These were obtained by grouping on a function, `groupby(df.sentences.str.contains(word, case=False))`, and then getting each group where this condition is `True`.

```
words = set()
_ = [words.add(word.lower()) for sentence in df.sentences for word in sentence.split()]

word_dict = {word: df.groupby(df.sentences.str.contains(word, case=False)).get_group(True) 
             for word in words}

>>> word_dict['temperature']
                                           sentences
0  two long pieces of metal fixed together, each ...
1            the temperature at which a liquid boils
2  a system for measuring temperature that is par...
3  a unit for measuring temperature. Measurements...
4  a system for measuring temperature in which wa...

>>> word_dict['freezes']
                                           sentences
2  a system for measuring temperature that is par...
4  a system for measuring temperature in which wa...

>>> words
{'0',
 '100',
 '212\xc2\xba',
 '32\xc2\xba',
 'a',
 'amount',
 'and',
 'are',
 'as',
 'at',
 'bends',
 ...
```

To get a dictionary of index values for each word:

```
>>> {word: word_dict[word].index.tolist() for word in word_dict}
{'0': [2],
 '100': [2],
 '212\xc2\xba': [4],
 '32\xc2\xba': [4],
 'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 'amount': [0],
 'and': [2, 4],
 'are': [0, 3],
 'as': [2, 3, 4],
 'at': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 'bends': [0],
 'boils': [1, 2, 4],
 'both': [0],
 'by': [3],
 'degrees': [2],
 'different': [0],
 'each': [0],
 'expressed': [3],
 'fixed': [0],
 'followed': [3],
 'for': [2, 3, 4],
 'freezes': [2, 4],
 ...
```

Or a matrix of boolean indicators.

```
>>> [df.sentences.str.contains(word, case='lower').tolist() for word in word_dict]
[[False, False, True, False, True],
 [False, False, False, True, False],
 [True, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False],
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your `TypeError` you can change your `lambda` to

```
lambda sentence: tuple(sentence.split())
```

which will return a `tuple` instead of a `list` (and `tuples` and hashable).

Comment: That does solve the error but I still can't get the right result (see edit)